# Choose Laravel LTS or latest version?

Tags: laravel, version, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.7

I want to start a new Laravel project, this project is a platform which may be we should develop and maintain for several years.

Now, I'm wondered to choose the correct Laravel version.

In the Laravel [Support Policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/releases#support-policy) page, Laravel said the 5.5 version will support until Aug 2020, but the 5.7 version will support until Sep 2019!

Which version I should choose for the new project?
Should I choose the latest version or long-term support version?

Comment: I'd honestly say it depends on your situation. I'm currently in a position where our application can't rely on  end of life framework versions and we upgraded to 5.6, so in the next month or so we'll be upgrading to 5.7....and onward until the next LTS simply because I don't want to have to deal with upgrading when a non-LTS reaches end of life.

Comment: Well its as @das mentioned. It depends on your needs. Personally, i always go for the most recent version when starting new projects. Especially if the new LTS versions contain new or useful features that you had to write custom code for.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the **latest version**.
Laravel is a robust framework, but its LTS is kind of a joke.

Just as an example, if you go with any laravel version below 5.7, you [can't have a working version](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/issues/317) of **[Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/socialite)** out of the box, due to the [latest Google changes](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown).
This is just an example as Socialite is not Laravel and only Laravel is LTS, it's still part of the ecosystem though.

So choose wisely as the migration process is not always very easy when you have the project in production.